# Batch processing in QGIS - points to path issues

Tags: qgis

I am trying to run Points to Path on a set of points files. When I do it one file at a time without batch processing, its fine and works as expected. However, even if I try batch processing a single file using the same parameters, I see that a suitably named file is created, but there is no content and also no CRS information. I have tried this on a couple of machines and get the same result. I really need to be able to automate the processing of these point files to paths.
Am running 3.34.1-Prizen.
Help?